# Defining a function to represent integers in Church numerals (DrRacket)

Tags: racket, church-encoding

I am trying to define a procedure that takes an integer and returns its representation in Church numerals. Could any one please help me figure out the mistake I am making? The following code it's what I have been able to do so far.

```lisp
(define succ
  (lambda (cn)
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (x)
        (f ((cn f) x))))))

(define (n->cn n)
  (if (= n 0)
      zero
      (succ (n->cn (lambda (x) (- x 1))))))
```

When I run the test:

```
(test (num->cn 3) three)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
exception (num->cn 3) at line 107
  expected: <no-expected-value>
=: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #<procedure:...ad/racket-file.rkt:99:21>
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
   0
```

It seems it's expecting a number? but a procedure is given. Which I think matches the intention of the procedure? Thanks for your help and comments for a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `n->ch` should be a number, not a procedure:

```
(define (n->cn n)
  (if (= n 0)
      zero
      (succ (n->cn (- n 1)))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sylwester. That was exactly the error.